# Date format in SSRS Expression

Tags: ssrs-expression, ssrs-2017

I am trying to change the date format for one of my field to dd/MM/yyyy but every time I used the below expression I get dd/MM/yyyy as the value in the cell instead of changing the format.

The data source that I am using is Teradata.

Expression used: =Format(FormatDateTime(Fields!DATE.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate),"dd/MM/yyyy")

Can some one help me with where am I going wrong. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FormatDateTime function returns a string instead of a date. When the FORMAT function tries to format it, it doesn't find a date field so it returns the characters in the format.

If your field is a date, you should be able to format the field without conversion:

```
=Format(Fields!DATE.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

If it does need to be converted first, try using the CDATE function:

```
=Format(CDATE(Fields!DATE.Value),"dd/MM/yyyy")
```